# Why do we need stride in CUDA kernel?

Tags: cuda

I was wondering, why do one need to use a [grid-stride](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/) stride in the following loop:

```
for (int i = index; i < ITERATIONS; i =+ stride)
{
  C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
}
```

Where we set stride and index to:

```
index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
```

When calling kernel we have this:

```
int blockSize = 5;
int ITERATIONS = 20;
int numBlocks = (ITERATIONS + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
bench<<<numBlocks, blockSize>>>(A, B, C);
```

So when we launch the kernel we will have blockDim.x = 5 and gridDim = 4 and there for stride will be equal 20.

My point is that, whenever one uses such approach, stride will always be equal or bigger than number of elements in calculation, so every time when it will come to increment loop will be over.

And here is the question, why one need to use loop or stride at all, why just not to run with index, like this?:

```
index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
C[index] = A[index] + B[index];
```

And another question, how can I now, in this particular case, how many thread is running on my GPU simultaneously before give a “jump” to another portion of a very big array (ex. 2000000)?

Comment: Sounds a bit like this: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/ story

Comment: The stride is what makes each thread also move in the y-axis inside it's block (assuming I understand your code)

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset, actually, in this case, I meant only x axis.

Comment: @Bart, yep, red it three times, but still have no solid clue why do one need stride...

Comment: The code to me only makes sense if you have a 2D matrix you're working on (or if you're splitting a 1D array into segments where stride is the length between segments, but then it resembles a 2dD matrix again)

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset, I was fallowing this tutoria (https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/even-easier-introduction-cuda/). Its 1D array sum.

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset: That isn't at all the case. The grid strided loop is there to allow a single thread to process multiple data without breaking coalesced memory access patterns

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset, thank you. I think its the answer what I was searching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My point is that, whenever one uses such approach, stride will always
>   be equal or bigger than number of elements in calculation, so every
>   time when it will come to increment loop will be over.

There lies the problem with your understanding. To use that kernel effectively, you only need to run as many blocks as will achieve maximal device wide occupancy for your device, not as many blocks as are required to process all your data. Those fewer blocks then become "resident" and process more than one input/output pair per thread. The grid stride also preserves whatever memory coalescing and cache coherency properties the kernel might have.

By doing this, you eliminate overhead from scheduling and retiring blocks. There can be considerable efficiency gains in simple kernels by doing so.  There is no other reason for this design pattern.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Just to make it more clear.
You're saying that this approach guarantees equal distribution of blocks on my GPS's SMs?
And without it I would just run everything on single SM?

Comment: No I am not saying anything like that. If you kernel had a maximum of three active blocks per SM and your GPU had 10 SM, run 30 blocks. It is that simple

Comment: Okay, got it.
So this is the sole purpose of grid-stride in this case?

Comment: For the benefit of readers, the prime reasons for the use of grid-stride approach is given [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/).